# JQuery Autocomplete - Select Multiple Values From Source

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am new to autocomplete.  I am able to get data from an API call and set that as the source, and make autocomplete work on a basic level.  But when I select a value, I also want to be able to:

1. Display the label in a text input while making the text input value the value of the source.
2. Automatically fill in some other inputs.

For example, I have 3 input boxes with the following ids:  customer, customer_number, customer_representative.  I have an API that returns the data in the following json format:

```
{"request":
   {"request_type":"whatever",
   "response":[
   {
      "customer_id":"123456",
      "customer_name":"TEST CUSTOMER",
      "customer_account":"ABC987",
      "customer_rep_id":"567",
       "customer_rep_id":"John Smith",
   }
   ]

   }
}
```

Here's my code so far:

```
var url = [API URL W/ PARAMS];
$.getJSON(url, function(data) 
{       
    var src = [];
    $.each(data.response, function(index, value) {
        var customer= data.response[index]['customer_name'];
        src.push(customer);
    });     

    $( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
        source: src
    });
}
```

This will enable autocomplete for the customer input box, but the value is the same as the customer name.  After reading through the  official documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), it seems that I should be able to use select( event, ui ) to at least populate the other 2 input boxes, but I'm at a loss how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it for a bit it finally clicked in my brain. 
To accomplish both, I just made the source a multi-dimensional array that included the extra values I wanted to retrieve, and then added a callback function to populate any other fields that I wanted filled out.

```
    var src = [];
     $.each(data.response, function(index, value) {
    var customer= data.response[index]['customer_name'];

     //Also retrieve other values that I want to use
     var customer_id= data.response[index]['customer_id'];
     var customer_rep_id= data.response[index]['customer_rep_id'];
     var customer_rep_name= data.response[index]['customer_rep_name'];

    //Make this a multi array
    src.push({label: customer, value:customer_id, rep_id = customer_rep_id, rep = customer_rep_name });
});   

//Added a callback function
$( "#customer" ).autocomplete({
    source: src,
    select: AutoCompleteSelectHandler
});


//This function auto-populates other inputs
function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui) { 
    //Populate rep box
    $("#customer_representative").val(ui.item.customer_rep_name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout lightweight DevBridge jQuery Autocomplete: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

You can pass any data with your suggestions and setup onSelect callback to handle values accordingly.